# how to notify parent class to update when child property changed in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Following is my sample codes. I'd like to know how to notify property both way from parent to child and child to parent.

for example, if I change carts, the

```
class Train  : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<Cart> carts { get; set; } 

    private int total_weight;
    public int Total_Weight // add up total carts weight
    {
        get => total_weight;
        set
        {
            total_weight = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    
}
    
class Cart : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Cart_No { get; set; }
    private int weight;
    public int Weight
    {
        get => weight;
        set
        {
            weight = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        // how to notify Train.total_weight to update ???
    
    }
}
```

Currently I can modify parent (train class) and notify change to child (cart), I also can update child class, but cannot notify parent class to update its property

So could anyone help? how to implement this event notification correctly. Or do i need a specific data colloction to do this

Thanks

Comment: The Train class could attach a PropertyChanged event handler to every Cart in the Carts list (the property name should use PascalCasing). Carts could also be an ObservableCollection, where the Train class could attach a CollectionChanged event handler to get notified about added or removed Carts.

Comment: @Clemens I guess that I can add PropertChanged to Train.Carts, but in this way, I have to go thru all cart elements in Carts list. Is it possible that I can notify which cart I changed (I added Cart_No property to codes) when I raise an event in Cart class? it seems I cannot notify property name from another class. Thanks

Comment: When a Cart fires its PropertyChanged event, it passes a reference to itself to the `sender` argument of the event handler method. Use that to identify which Cart has changed.

Comment: You could also implement the TotalWeight like this: `public int TotalWeight => Carts.Sum(c => c.Weight);`. Whenever a Carts' PropertyChanged event is fired, just call `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalWeight));`.

Comment: I think you need to implement an event handler.